# C++ convert from object to array of std::size_t with minimal overhead

Tags: c++, hash

I'm writing some kind of hash function.

For object `obj` of type `T` that satisfy `std::is_trivial_v<T>`, if `sizeof(T) > sizeof(std::size_t)`, I want to compute hash function like this:

1. Convert `obj` to a sequence of `length = sizeof(T) / sizeof(size_t) + ((sizeof(T) % sizeof(size_t)) ? 1 : 0)` number of `size_t`, using `std::bit_cast` (Say this as `my_bit_convert()`)
2. Compute the hash value like this:

```
array<size_t, length> obj_repr = my_bit_convert(obj);
size_t val = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  val = my_hash_function(obj_repr[i] + val);
}
return val;
```

I think I can refactor the 2. part to `constexpr` operations, but I want to do the 1. part with minimal overhead, ideally as `constexpr`.

I've tried `std::variant` but the performance was awful, is there a better alternative?

For example, if `sizeof(T) == 44`, I want to get six `size_t` from `obj` with type `T` (in 64bit machines where `unsigned char` has 8 bits)

Comment: By any description it is trivial to write C++ programs with awful performance. Better alternative is to post your actual, working code to codereview.stackexchange.com People who read it can have ideas

Comment: Not sure if it will be faster or not, but you can use `std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&T), sizeof(T)))`

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm now trying ```std::memcpy``` to ```std::array<std::size_t, length>``` and performance seems much better (but it is not compile time). I'm still curious if there is a faster alternative

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ever be able to do this in compile time.  reinterpreting is not allowed in constan expressions and that is basically what you want to do, treat the bytes of a `T` as a `U`.

Comment: This is very very bad idea. Remember that fields have alignment, so there may be unused spaces between fields with random content. This means that for some items which are equal your can have different hash with this approach!!! Also there are types like `double` which can be equal but bit representation is different.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, I found that ```std::bit_cast<std::array<std::size_t, length>>(obj)``` solves the problem, ```std::bit_cast``` is ```constexpr```

Comment: I keep forgetting about that one.  Do note that it was just introduced in C++20 so using it will limit your poratability.

Comment: @MarekR I found that for the classes whose some fields have padding, ```std::bit_cast``` does not work as ```constexpr```, so it can be guarded at compile-time (Omitting ```constexpr``` still makes potential problem, admittedly)

Comment: Padding bytes have indeterminate values, it may not be a good idea to hash them.

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented my hash function for span-like types.

```
template <typename T>
concept Scalar = is_scalar_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept SpanType = !Scalar<T> && requires(T t) {
  t.data();
  t.size();
};

inline constexpr size_t hash_a_base = 123UL;

template <size_t a> struct HashFunc {
  constexpr size_t operator()(size_t k) const noexcept {
    return 2 * k * k + a * k;
  }
};

template <unsigned_integral T, size_t a> struct HashBase {
  constexpr size_t operator()(T k) const noexcept {
    // TODO: take care when sizeof(T) > sizeof(size_t)...
    return HashFunc<a + sizeof(T) * 16>{}(static_cast<size_t>(k));
  }
};

template <Scalar T, size_t a> struct HashImpl {
  constexpr size_t operator()(const T &key) const noexcept {
    if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(uint64_t)) {
      return HashBase<uint64_t, a>{}(bit_cast<uint64_t>(key));
    } else if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(uint8_t)) {
      return HashBase<uint8_t, a>{}(bit_cast<uint8_t>(key));
    } else if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(uint16_t)) {
      return HashBase<uint16_t, a>{}(bit_cast<uint16_t>(key));
    } else if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(uint32_t)) {
      return HashBase<uint32_t, a>{}(bit_cast<uint32_t>(key));
    } else {
      []<bool flag = false>() {
        static_assert(flag, "Not supported sizeof(T)");
      }
      ();
    }
  }
};

template <SpanType T>
using SpanBaseType = remove_pointer_t<decltype(data<T>(declval<T>()))>;
template <size_t a> struct HashSpan {
  size_t operator()(span<const size_t> arr) const noexcept {
    size_t val = arr.size();
    for (auto num : arr) {
      val = detail::HashBase<size_t, a>{}(num + val);
    }
    return val;
  }

  size_t operator()(span<const unsigned char> arr, size_t val) const noexcept {
    for (auto num : arr) {
      val = detail::HashBase<size_t, a>{}(static_cast<size_t>(num) + val);
    }
    return val;
  }
};

} // namespace detail

template <typename T, size_t a = detail::hash_a_base> struct Hash {
  constexpr size_t operator()(const T &key) const noexcept requires(Scalar<T>) {
    // negative zero -> positive zero for floating points
    if constexpr (is_same_v<T, float>) {
      return detail::HashImpl<T, a>{}(key == 0.0f ? 0.0f : key);
    } else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, double>) {
      return detail::HashImpl<T, a>{}(key == 0.0 ? 0.0 : key);
    } else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, long double>) {
      return detail::HashImpl<T, a>{}(key == 0.0l ? 0.0l : key);
    } else {
      return detail::HashImpl<T, a>{}(key);
    }
  }

  constexpr size_t operator()(const T &key) const noexcept requires(SpanType<T>) {
    using base_type = detail::SpanBaseType<T>;

    auto num_bytes = key.size() * sizeof(base_type);

    if (num_bytes == 0) {
      return 0UL;
    } else {
      auto num_words = num_bytes / sizeof(size_t);
      size_t val = 0;
      if (num_words) {
        val = detail::HashSpan<a>{}(span{reinterpret_cast<const size_t *>(key.data()), num_words});
      }
      auto last_bytes = num_bytes % sizeof(size_t);
      if (last_bytes) {
        return detail::HashSpan<a>{}(span{reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(key.data() + num_words), last_bytes}, last_bytes + val);
      } else {
        return val;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

For `std::string` with long length, this function was much faster than `std::hash<std::string>`.

Benchmark result: (Generated 10000 random `std::string` with length 1~500, with `char` having values 32~126, and inserted them in random order, retrieved in random order, erased in random order. Tried this 1000 times)

```
std::unordered_set<std::string, std::hash<std::string>> test
Time to insert  10000 elements:
Average : 10980.6104 us,
Stdev   :   973.3181 us,
95%     : 13485.1094 us,
99%     : 14788.1992 us,
99.9%   : 14824.3770 us,

Time to find  10000 elements:
Average :  4738.7148 us,
Stdev   :   782.7706 us,
95%     :  6460.4658 us,
99%     :  7513.4780 us,
99.9%   :  9732.9951 us,

Time to erase  10000 elements:
Average :  5242.2021 us,
Stdev   :   975.2573 us,
95%     :  6961.9961 us,
99%     : 10397.3525 us,
99.9%   : 11742.9883 us,

std::unordered_set<std::string, frozenca::hard::Hash<std::string>> test
Time to insert  10000 elements:
Average :  4377.6470 us,
Stdev   :   411.8980 us,
95%     :  5214.9204 us,
99%     :  6192.5166 us,
99.9%   :  6333.6099 us,

Time to find  10000 elements:
Average :  2407.2400 us,
Stdev   :   725.3784 us,
95%     :  3846.8633 us,
99%     :  6181.4131 us,
99.9%   :  7530.2129 us,

Time to erase  10000 elements:
Average :  3017.9241 us,
Stdev   :   766.5061 us,
95%     :  5034.3765 us,
99%     :  6032.3950 us,
99.9%   :  7971.5703 us,
```